# How can I keep background tasks alive in background on Android using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, background, task

I have a bussness app that count time, set macros and show notification and alerts.
I have a problem when app goes to background and Android stop my counting tasks.

I tried many things to keep these tasks alive, but I failed. This notification need to work offline, so FCM not a good solution.

How can I work arround it?

Obs.: When app goes to foreground, all tasks work and show all notifications... But I need to alert user just in time, not only in foreground.

---

I founded a solution!

Searching the site https://dontkillmyapp.com/ I saw many apps with the same problem and some solution ideas for differets brands and models.

After checking some of them, I saw that many installed apps has this config for default, so I search how can I do it programactlly.

Here the solution:

pubspec.yaml

```json
  android_power_manager: ^0.1.6
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
```

Function:

```dart
void init() async {
    var status = await Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations.status;
    print("status: $status");
    if (status.isGranted) {
      print(
          "isIgnoring: ${(await AndroidPowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations)}");
      if (!(await AndroidPowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations)) {
        AndroidPowerManager.requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations();
      }
    } else {
      Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
        Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations,
      ].request();
      print(
          "permission value: ${statuses[Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations]}");
      if (statuses[Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations].isGranted) {
        AndroidPowerManager.requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations();
      } else {
        exit(0);
      }
    }
  }
```

AppWidget.dart (main)

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    init();

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    DataTransferService().initTimerTask();
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: Modular.navigatorKey,
      title: APP_NAME,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => LoginPage(),
        '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/notification': (context) => NotificationPage(),
        '/alerts': (context) => AlertsPage(),
      },
      onGenerateRoute: Modular.generateRoute,
    );
  }
```

So, the app ask permission (if needed) and, if permission is granted, ask user to set app to ignore battery optimization.

Now the notifications are working all rigt! =]

Comment: did you add "android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" in your manifest? and won't this lead to reject of play store?

Comment: Yes. In final solution I used this permission. Play Store accept, but flagged that I have ads in my app... I don't know why, but still works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want an [Android service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) to run these tasks (foreground or background depending on your specific requirements).

It looks like there are some Flutter [packages](https://pub.dev/packages?q=foreground%20service) that have already been built to help with this, but I'd pay close attention to what they offer in terms of support for different Android versions.

Comment: I search a lot in your "logic" and I found one solution (for while)
I will edit my post to share this solution